# 'Is too many', 'are too many' or something else?

Tags: grammar

*"I decided to go on holiday for a week. I think 10 days **is** too many for me."*

Am I correct using *'is'* instead of *'are'?* Or the only way is to change the phrase to *'10-days period is too long for me?'*

Comment: Related question, [Is it “5–6 weeks are a lot of time” or “5–6 weeks is a lot of time”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/is-it-5-6-weeks-are-a-lot-of-time-or-5-6-weeks-is-a-lot-of-time), [“Four years are” vs. “four years is”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177112/four-years-are-vs-four-years-is).

Comment: Thanks, Rathony, should I delete my question then?

Comment: No, you can't delete your question after it is answered and the below answer is accepted. Your question will be closed as duplicate as the question on "four years are" vs "four years is" was closed. Please try to use the search before posting a question next time. Happy holidays!

Comment: Happy holidays to you too! Tbh, our (orthodox) Christmas will be on the 7-th of January, and that sentence I've just made up as an example. ;) I had no idea how to find a similar question, what collocation to use for it. :/

Comment: It is not that easy as your question doesn't contain a key word for search. If you type "years is years are" in the search as in [the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=years+is+years+are), you will see the duplicate question> Again, it is not that easy. :-)

Comment: Yes, and of course I didn't know that one of that two questions had a  " years' " context.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ungrammatical, but it is unnatural.

Consider the more natural "ten days is too long for me".

"Ten days" is conceptualised there as a single abstact entity, hence singular "is".

Comment: Do I understand you right that though the word 'period' is only implied, it's correct to say '**ten days** is too **long**'?

Comment: @Артём Луговой Yes, "ten days is too long" is perfectly natural, I can assure you.