# "Two cars are luxury" or "Two cars is luxury"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Here is the sentence,

> I'm getting rid of one of my cars, because two cars are/is luxury

I think the latter is correct, because two cars together constitutes to luxury. In case of,

> Cars are luxury

Here even having one car constitutes to luxury.

Please tell me if I'm right or wrong here.

Comment: because [having] two cars is a luxury

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Is too many', 'are too many' or something else?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296114/is-too-many-are-too-many-or-something-else) 'Six children is too many' is a common employment of notional agreement ('A person having six children? That is [just] too many.') The six children are regarded as a composite unity.  But I'd rephrase 'Two cars is two many' as it sounds faintly ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I dare not say you're right or wrong. Here are my suggestions:
I'm getting rid of one of my cars, because having two cars is a luxury
or I'm getting rid of one of my cars, because having two cars is luxurious.
Hope my suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).